# Filter that's neither Principal nor Ultrafilter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

- The Fréchet Filter: <strike>smallest non-principal ultrafilter.</strike>
- The family of supersets of $\{1,2\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$: smallest filter containing $\{1,2\}$. Principal. Not an ultrafilter.
- Any ultrafilter over a finite set is principal.

**Are there filters that are neither principal nor an ultrafilter?**

An example would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Fréchet filter $F$ isn't the smallest non-principal ultrafilter. It's the filter consisting of all cofinite sets. And it's not an ultrafilter, since any infinite/co-infinite $X$ has $X\notin F$ and $X^c\notin F.$ As such, it's an excellent example of a filter that is not an ultrafilter and is not principal.

Comment: Another nice example on $\Bbb N$: All $A\subseteq \Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{n \notin A} \frac{1}{n}$ converges. Think about it, it's properly bigger than the Fréchet filter, but not an ultrafilter.

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake, I should've read my text more carefully (I read "to find a nonprincipal ultrafilter [on an infinite set] it is enough to find an ultrafilter that extends the filter of cofinite sets", but missed the infinite and second ultrafilter parts. Sorry!). In any case, thank you very much for the answer!